# how to convert a string vector containing relation operators to a vector of intervals?

Tags: r

I have a dataset where one column should be numeric value but some rows have values containg relation operators like '>=' or '<='. To simplify this, consider I have a vector:

```
a <- c('>= 0.99', '0.66', '<= 0.01')
```

how should I convert it to a numeric vector of intervals like:

```
library(intervals)
b <- Intervals(cbind(left = c(0.99, 0.66, -Inf), right = c(Inf, 0.66, 0.01)))
b
# Object of class Intervals
# 3 intervals over R:
# [0.99, Inf]
# [0.66, 0.66]
# [-Inf, 0.01]
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: It wouldn't maintain any extra non-numeric characters and be numeric

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and add the expected output in the Q, not in the comments. Thank you.

Comment: @UweBlock, does it looks fine now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe you can use **switch** to solve your problem.

```
a <- c('>= 0.99', '= 0.66', '<= 0.01')
oper_num <- matrix(unlist(strsplit(a," "), recursive = T), ncol=2, byrow = T)
limits <- function(vec){
  operation = vec[1]
  number = vec[2]
  switch(
    operation,
    ">=" = paste0("[", number,", Inf]"),
    ">" =paste0("(", number, ", Inf]"),
    "=" = paste0("[", number, ", ", number, "]"),
    "<" = paste0("[-Inf, ", number, ")"),
    "<=" =paste0("[-Inf, ", number, "]")
  )
}
apply(oper_num, 1, limits)
#> [1] "[0.99, Inf]"    "[0.66, 0.66]"   "[-Inf, 0.01]"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `parse_number`

```
library(readr)
parse_number(a)
#[1] 0.51 0.33 0.99 0.66 0.01
```

Comment: sorry I edited the question. but this function is really convenient.

Answer (score 0):

With a regular expression and the function gsub():

```
a <- c('.51', '.33', '> .99', '.66', '<= .01')
a.n <- gsub("<|>|=| ", "", a)
n <- as.numeric(a.n)
n
[1] 0.51 0.33 0.99 0.66 0.01
```

See ?regexp or gsub for more help.